# I am trying to modify the table's title with bold

Tags: captions, bold

I have the following minimal example:

```
\documentclass[12pt, oneside]{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=1in]{geometry}


\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h!]
\caption{Final candidate genes}\label{tab:final}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{ll}
\toprule
& Gene\\
\midrule
Amplifications & ERLIN2 \\
& ERBB2 \\
& GAB1 \\
& PIK3CA\\
& PTK2 \\
\addlinespace
Deletions & SFMBT1 \\
& LATS1 \\
& MGAM \\
& PRSS2 \\
& DEFB130 \\
& ANXA8 \\
& PPYR1 \\
& FGFR2 \\
& CENTD2 \\
& PDE2A \\
& P2RY5 \\
& DNAH9 \\
& MAP2K4 \\
& ZNF18 \\
& FAM101B \\
& VPS53 \\
\bottomrule

\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

When I run it, I would like for "Table 1" to appear in bold. Is there a simple package for that? Thank you! :)

Comment: **caption** ...?

Answer (score 4):

Just use **caption**:

```
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup{labelfont={bf}}
```

I minimised your example somewhat:

[image: bold caption label]

Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs,caption}
\captionsetup{labelfont=bf}
\begin{document}
  \begin{table}
    \caption{Final candidate genes}\label{tab:final}
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{ll}
      \toprule
      Antelopes & Bazookas\\
      \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
  \end{table}
\end{document}
```